# Trigger checkbox created dynamically to apply semantic-ui and its features

Tags: jquery, angularjs, checkbox, semantic-ui

I have list data `$scope.displayMatches = []` to render on table using `ng-repeat`.

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="match in displayMatches">
      <td>{{match.Name}}</td>
      <td colspan="2">
          <div class="ui fitted toggle checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{match.Resigned}}"><label></label>
          </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

The list data is loaded in async mode and then checkbox is created dynamically.
How can I apply semantic-ui checkbox event like `beforeChecked` and `onChanged` events to each of checkbox?

Comment: Please don't use `{{` & `}}` in angular's default directives

Comment: How should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Tested and confirm it works

```
$scope.initCheckbox = function () {
    $('.ui.checkbox').checkbox({
        beforeChecked: function () {
            alert(0);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function () {
            alert(1);
        }
    });
}
```

And in view, add `ng-init`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{match.Resigned}}" ng-init="initCheckbox()"><label></label>
```

That's it